# EOF suddenly reaching with getline() in ifstream

Tags: c++

I have file "in.txt" which consist of 2 strings:

```
abcde
12345
```

I have my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
   std::ifstream fileIn("in.txt", std::ios::in);

   char* chPtr = new(char[10]);
   char ch;

   printf("fileIn.get()==EOF?: %d \n", (fileIn.get() == EOF));  // =0
   std::cout << "fileIn.eof() = " << fileIn.eof() << "\n";  // =0

   fileIn.getline(chPtr, 3);
   std::cout << "chPtr-" << chPtr << "\n";  //output:"bc" (see 1.)
   fileIn.get(ch);
   std::cout << "ch-" << ch << "\n";   //(see 2.)

   printf("fileIn.get()==EOF?: %d \n", (fileIn.get() == EOF));  // =1 (see 3.)
   std::cout << "fileIn.eof() = " << fileIn.eof() << "\n";  // =0 (see 4.)

   fileIn.close();
   delete[] chPtr;  
}
```

**Remarks to code:**

(**1.**) 1st symbol 'a' was eaten by get() slightly above; Thus 2 next symbols read here, and 3rd symbol, what i wanted to read, getline() automatically assigns with value '\0' (if I understand correctly).

(**2.**)And here are is the question - here outputs symbol (with code [-52]). Unfortunately I haven't enough reputation to post images =( (This symbol is like 2 vertical white lines, right line of this pair is with gap at the middle). 
(for information: I got this symbol each time, I'm trying to read to char variable an uninitialized element of char-array.) 
But why I get it there?? Because there are still unreaded symbols in 1st string & whole 2nd string!

(**3.**) It turns out that, the cursor suddenly moved to the end of file. But WHY?? I can't understand

(**4.**) We still have zero here, because (if I understand correctly) there was not attempt of reading data behind the eof-line. The cursor just moved to place behind the last symbol of file, but not out of the file-end-border).

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I asked (if concisely), why after statement fileIn.get(ch); i don't get ch=='d', but ch== symbol with char-code -52 //i.e. (int)ch ==-52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `istream::getline` manages to read `count-1`  characters (`count` is 3 in your example) before `EOF` is reached, it will set `failbit`. See the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

This means all further extractions will fail unless you clear the flag, not that "cursor moved to the end". `ch` never gets initialized.

Comment: If I understood [information](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) correctly, `fialbit` flag is set, when:
- `(count-1)` characters are red & no EOF or delim was reached, 
- next one character (after `count-1`) also is not delim.
Thanks for your hint.
I still don't understand, why checking for EOF give me `true` when failbit flag set, but i assume, that it's side effect of this flag's set.